# How can we predict the colour of transition metal complexes?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds, transition-metals, color

I am facing problems in indentifying colour of complex compunds just by seeing the their molecular formula. Is there any method or concept to predict the colour of complex compunds?

Comment: See presence of unpaired electrons, complexes having unpaired elctrons absorb visible radiations for d d transitions.

Comment: I am asking if a compound is given to us and we need to determine whether it is yellow coloured or not so can we predict that?

Comment: The coordination geometry + central metal ion + spin state often gives a good guess what kind of color you will see. However, it is not exact science (if you don't do any calculations), especially with charge transfer bands.

Comment: Can you provide some examples using the three properties just mentioned ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic principle of coloured compounds is that there is some kind of electronic transition whose energy difference corresponds to a photon whose wavelength is in the visible region ($\pu{400nm}<\lambda<\pu{700nm}$). Thus, to determine the colour of a compound we should always be looking at the molecular orbital scheme; for reference, I have attached the MO scheme of a typical octahedral $\ce{[ML6]^n+}$ compound in figure 1.

[image: octahedral]
**Figure 1:** Octahedral $\ce{[ML6]}$ complex with no π interactions. Image copied from [this answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/38339/7475) and originally taken from [Professor Klüfers’ internet scriptum to his coordination chemistry course](http://www.cup.lmu.de/ac/kluefers/homepage/L_kc.html).

The most common electronic transition corresponding to visible wavelengths is the transition between $\mathrm{t_{2g}}$ and $\mathrm{e_g^*}$, marked with $\pu{10Dq}$ in figure 1. In simple terms, these five orbitals correspond to the central metal’s $\mathrm{d}$ orbitals meaning that the metal’s electronic configuration plus the strength of the $\ce{L\bond{->}M}$ interaction will determine the colour.

The problem with attempting to predict colours *ab initio* is that you cannot really predict the difference in energy levels between the ligand orbitals (right-hand side) and metal orbitals (left hand side) — it is mostly the metal and its oxidation state that determines this, a higher oxidation state corresponding to lower-lying metal orbitals, therefore a greater value of $\pu{10Dq}$ and therefore a blue-shift in colour.

However, there are still a few shortcuts that you can use assuming you have memorised the ‘general colour’ of a certain metal in a certain oxidation state. For example, you may consider stronger and weaker field ligands. When going from a slightly weaker ligand to a slightly stronger ligand — e.g. going from $\ce{[Cu(H2O)6]^2+}$ to $\ce{[Cu(NH3)4(H2O)2]^2+}$ — $\pu{10Dq}$ is predicted to increase and thus the absorbed wavelength predicted to decrease.

Unfortunately, the generality of this scheme is strongly limited. It fails as soon as:

- the complex transitions from a high-spin state to a low-spin state (e.g. $\ce{[Fe(H2O)6]^3+}$ to $\ce{[Fe(CN)6]^3-}$)
- the geometry of the complex changes from (distorted) octahedral to something else like tetrahedral (e.g. $\ce{[Co(H2O)6]^3+}$ to $\ce{[CoCl4]-}$).

So you might just be better off memorising the colours of certain complexes rather than attempting to learn the pattern and remember the exceptions.